# Kubernetes Load Balancer always forwarding request to the same pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have RTMP Load balancer but all requests always go to the same POD. So what exactly am I missing?

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rtmp-server
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: RTMP
    port: 1935
    targetPort: 1935
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: rtmp-servers
```

Comment: Not sure if you config the pods correctly. You can try to verify that the service is correctly configured to select all the healthy pods by running the `kubectl get endpoints <service-name>` command first, which should show the IP addresses of all the pods that are part of the service.

Comment: FYI, [this article](https://blog.getambassador.io/load-balancing-strategies-in-kubernetes-l4-round-robin-l7-round-robin-ring-hash-and-more-6a5b81595d6c) explains the load balancing strategies in k8s and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) is information about kube-proxy

Comment: Thanks for your response. All endpoints are going to the right pods. 2 endpoints and 2 pods. I mean matched entpoint address with pods.

Comment: As mentioned before, LoadBalancer has different strategies for request forwarding. It can be random or round-robin or other algorithms. It depends on the cloud provider. You can check the documentation of your cloud provider to see if they provide any options to configure the load-balancing algorithm. If you just want to test if all the endpoint pods are available, maybe you can try to send lots of requests (by some load test tool such as wrk2) in a short time and check if they are forwarded to different pods.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved ? Refer to these [stackpost1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583212/kubernetes-is-always-forwarding-the-request-to-same-pod), [stackpost2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737766/kubernetes-traffic-always-redirect-to-the-same-pod) .Let me know if this helps.